# Spring mvc: Controller Result resent to RequestMappingHandlerMapping

Tags: spring-mvc

I have an abstract Spring Controller class extended by various controllers.
Example method:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllAsView(@RequestParam(required = false) boolean ajax,
        Model m) {
    String mapping = elementClass.getSimpleName();
    m.addAttribute(mapping + "List", getAll());
    return mapping + "All" + (ajax ? "Ajax" : "");
}
```

These are the relevant definitions in my view.xml:

```
<definition name="maintemplate" template="/WEB-INF/views/main_template.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="top" value="/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="side" value="/WEB-INF/views/menu.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="ajaxtemplate" template="/WEB-INF/views/ajax_template.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="top" value="/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="PersonAll" extends="maintemplate">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/personlist.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="PersonAllAjax" template="ajaxtemplate">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/personlist.jsp" />
</definition>
```

With the ajax parameter only the body content is to return.

Everything works fine without the ajax parameter.
But with the Ajax parameter the return string is used for a new Controller request.
This is the Log:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /person/6
TRACE: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod - Invoking [PersonController.getAsView] method with arguments [6, true, {}]
WARN : de.kreth.clubhelperbackend.aspects.DaoLoggerAspect - de.kreth.clubhelperbackend.dao.PersonDao.getById(6) ==> 6: M Kreth
TRACE: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod - Method [getAsView] returned [PersonGetAjax]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /person/ajaxtemplate
```

This is the servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="de.kreth.clubhelperbackend" />

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
                    <property name="dateFormat">
                        <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
                            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String"
                                value="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS Z"></constructor-arg>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="2" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

I am stuck finding out what is happening here. I changed the template name and the new name was used for the request.

The problem came up, after I changed nearly all xml files in project. I inserted Doctype tag and changed schema definitions and stuff. Because that caused heavy problems I stepped back to a working version. Before that, the ajax parameter worked.
Ah - and I updated to java-version 1.6.

Any ideas why spring uses the templatename "ajaxtemplate" as a new request and sends it back to the controller?

Best regards
Markus

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake: never programm past midnight:

```
<definition name="PersonAllAjax" template="ajaxtemplate">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/personlist.jsp" />
</definition>
```

must be

```
<definition name="PersonAllAjax" extends="ajaxtemplate">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/personlist.jsp" />
</definition>
```